# C3 Vsto Outook addin - resource managable by user

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, add-in, embedded-resource

I'm trying to create an addin to Outlook in Visual Studio. What is does is basically create and winform, lets user choose items in several listboxes and then creates an email. One of the requirements is to have some of listboxes easily changed/populated by user.

I managed to make it populated on form load from .txt resource files but it works only on my computer. I cannot find those txt file after I install the file on users computer and listboxes don't get populated. What do I have to have those text file visible and editable by the user?

Comment: It might be helpful to include a few relevant bits of coped - probably just the bits showing how you load the text files.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find those txt file after I install the file on users computer and listboxes don't get populated.

It looks like you didn't include the required .txt files to the installer (or resources). See the [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) section in MSDN for more information.